# Octopack is not packing when using custom nuspec file

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, octopus-deploy, octopack

I am attempting to configure an octopus deployment build in TFS.
It was working okay initially, as in it would build, package up using octopack and deploy.

However i want to configure what files get packed and realised that I need to use a custom nuspec file.

I created a new file and used a default .nuspec file with no changes as a starting point.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>Package</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>me</authors>
    <owners>me</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2015</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="SampleDependency" version="1.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

With this file present and checked in when I do a build it is not creating a nuget package.

As soon as I exclude the nuspec file it all works again.

The nuspec file is `My.Project.Name.nuspec`

Answer (score 0):

Okay i have got it working again.

The package was getting made it seems that octopus was not picking it up.
It seems that the `<id>Package</id>` is also very important and should be named the same as the project and nuspec file.

Comment: The name of the .nuspec file is very important for Octopack to function and this must match the name of the project. You can tailor the id property  (it doesn't have to match) as this is used to drive the name of the .nupkg it produces.

Comment: I think it is to do with the fact I have automatic release creation turned on in octopus but it was not generating a nuget package for me as far as i could see unless both the id and filename of the nuspec file matched the project name.